# Failed to install scitools-iris using pip: ImportError No module named target_pkg (in pyke)

Tags: python, linux, python-2.7, python-iris, pyke

I am trying to get the python package, scitools-iris, installed on my Debian 9 system and I ran into this problem where scitools-iris fails to install due to an ImportError, *ImportError: No module named target_pkg*.

I am using python 2.7 and all packages are installed using pip only. I have installed PyKE as shown in [here](https://pyke.keplerscience.org/install.html):
`pip install pyketools --user`
and I can import PyKE in python using import pyke without any error.
Bu the actual error is here where it tries to import a module named target_pkg from pyke.target_pkg. I tried the import statement in python,
`from pyke.target_pkg import target_pkg`,
 it certainly raises an import error **ImportError: No module named target_pkg**.

How do I get around this problem and install iris in my system?
Have I installed the wrong package for PyKE?

Answer (score 3):

Found out what I have been doing wrong. I actually had the wrong package installed for PyKE using pip. I installed [pyketools](https://pypi.org/project/pyketools/), which is also called PyKE instead of the actual [PyKE (Python Knowledge Engine and Automatic Python Program Generator)](https://pypi.org/project/pyke/).
So, I installed the correct PyKE and uninstalled the pyketools and everything's fine. Couldn't get pip to install PyKE, so had to download it from [here](https://sourceforge.net/projects/pyke/) and install it.

Comment: Di you found a version of pyke that works with python3 ?

Comment: found it here https://sourceforge.net/projects/pyke/files/pyke/1.1.1/pyke3-1.1.1.zip